# Stripe payment method Magento2

Tags: magento2, stripe

Can anyone explain me about stripe payment method. Also i have to create a custom payment method using stripe payment. Please guide accordingly

Answer (score 1):

**Stripe Payment** is one solution to cover all your payments needs.

- It provide your **payments flow with comprehensive security**, including **3D Secure support**
- Offer **real-time payments via automatic invoicing**
- Efficient configuration management and **flexible refund** issuing options
- **Adapt to different screen sizes** (from desktop to mobile) and invoke the numeric keyboard where relevant.

> Basically if there is two option **first** you can purchase this Stripe Module with Magento store or **Second** you can create of your own.

If you want to create of your own, you need to follow this basic steps:

1. **Create System.xml File**

File is used to create the store configuration part for the extension so that the configuration for setting up the payment method can be done from admin panel easily. We will define several fields like API Key, Supported Credit Card Types etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="excellence_stripe" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Stripe</label>
                <comment>
                    <![CDATA[<a href="https://stripe.com/" target="_blank">Click here to sign up for Stripe account</a>]]>
                </comment>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="api_key" translate="label" type="obscure" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Api Key</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted</backend_model>
                </field>
                <field id="debug" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Debug</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="cctypes" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Credit Card Types</label>
                    <source_model>Excellence\Stripe\Model\Source\Cctype</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Sort Order</label>
                </field>
                <field id="allowspecific" translate="label" type="allowspecific" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="51" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="min_order_total" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="98" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
                </field>
                <field id="max_order_total" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="99" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Maximum Order Total</label>
                    <comment>Leave empty to disable limit</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

2. Crate Model File

We will create a Model for handling the processing of payment and will define this model is the config.xml:

```
<?php

namespace Excellence\Stripe\Model;

class Payment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc
{
    const CODE = 'excellence_stripe';

    protected $_code = self::CODE;

    protected $_isGateway                   = true;
    protected $_canCapture                  = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial           = true;
    protected $_canRefund                   = true;
    protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial     = true;

    protected $_stripeApi = false;

    protected $_countryFactory;

    protected $_minAmount = null;
    protected $_maxAmount = null;
    protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('USD');

    protected $_debugReplacePrivateDataKeys = ['number', 'exp_month', 'exp_year', 'cvc'];

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleList,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Stripe\Stripe $stripe,
        array $data = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $extensionFactory,
            $customAttributeFactory,
            $paymentData,
            $scopeConfig,
            $logger,
            $moduleList,
            $localeDate,
            null,
            null,
            $data
        );

        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;

        $this->_stripeApi = $stripe;
        $this->_stripeApi->setApiKey(
            $this->getConfigData('api_key')
        );

        $this->_minAmount = $this->getConfigData('min_order_total');
        $this->_maxAmount = $this->getConfigData('max_order_total');
    }

    /**
     * Payment capturing
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment
     * @param float $amount
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception
     */
    public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        //throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Inside Stripe, throwing donuts :]'));

        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $payment->getOrder();

        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address $billing */
        $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();

        try {
            $requestData = [
                'amount'        => $amount * 100,
                'currency'      => strtolower($order->getBaseCurrencyCode()),
                'description'   => sprintf('#%s, %s', $order->getIncrementId(), $order->getCustomerEmail()),
                'card'          => [
                    'number'            => $payment->getCcNumber(),
                    'exp_month'         => sprintf('%02d',$payment->getCcExpMonth()),
                    'exp_year'          => $payment->getCcExpYear(),
                    'cvc'               => $payment->getCcCid(),
                    'name'              => $billing->getName(),
                    'address_line1'     => $billing->getStreetLine(1),
                    'address_line2'     => $billing->getStreetLine(2),
                    'address_city'      => $billing->getCity(),
                    'address_zip'       => $billing->getPostcode(),
                    'address_state'     => $billing->getRegion(),
                    'address_country'   => $billing->getCountryId(),
                    // To get full localized country name, use this instead:
                    // 'address_country'   => $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($billing->getCountryId())->getName(),
                ]
            ];

            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create($requestData);
            $payment
                ->setTransactionId($charge->id)
                ->setIsTransactionClosed(0);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->debugData(['request' => $requestData, 'exception' => $e->getMessage()]);
            $this->_logger->error(__('Payment capturing error.'));
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Payment capturing error.'));
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Payment refund
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment
     * @param float $amount
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception
     */
    public function refund(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        $transactionId = $payment->getParentTransactionId();

        try {
            \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($transactionId)->refund(['amount' => $amount * 100]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->debugData(['transaction_id' => $transactionId, 'exception' => $e->getMessage()]);
            $this->_logger->error(__('Payment refunding error.'));
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Payment refunding error.'));
        }

        $payment
            ->setTransactionId($transactionId . '-' . \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::TYPE_REFUND)
            ->setParentTransactionId($transactionId)
            ->setIsTransactionClosed(1)
            ->setShouldCloseParentTransaction(1);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Determine method availability based on quote amount and config data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface|null $quote
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    {
        if ($quote && (
            $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() < $this->_minAmount
            || ($this->_maxAmount && $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() > $this->_maxAmount))
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->getConfigData('api_key')) {
            return false;
        }

        return parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }

    /**
     * Availability for currency
     *
     * @param string $currencyCode
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
    {
        if (!in_array($currencyCode, $this->_supportedCurrencyCodes)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this file, there are two main methods:

```
capture(): This method is handling the process of charging the credit card and saving the transaction. We are just fetching the billing address details from payment object, and the passing it to stripe API along with card details and order amount. The API will process this data and will return a charge object. We are just saving its id as transaction id for the order.
refund(): This method will be used to process the refund. The previously saved transaction id will be sent to the API and then refund will be processed.
```

**Now you have to create your Stripe Account** with Sandbox

**Generate API key:** To Create a sandbox account, go to https://dashboard.stripe.com/register and enter the required details and Sign Up. After creating the account, you will need to access the API key which needs to be entered in Payment Configuration (in Magento Admin Panel). Navigate to Developers -> API Keys. Here you will get two keys, Publishable key and Secret key.

You need to use the Secret key only. Copy it and save somewhere.

Now, we will see where to put the API key and how to do other configurations for the payment method, we have created. For this, navigate to Store -> Configuration -> Payment Methods -> Stripe

Here you can enter the API key and do other settings also.

Now this will works.

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

To use Stripe payment method in Magento 2, you first need to create a Stripe account and obtain the API keys for your account. Once you have the API keys, you can configure the Stripe payment method in your Magento 2 store by following these steps:

- Log in to your Magento 2 admin panel and go to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods.
- Scroll down and find the Stripe payment method, and click on it to expand the settings.
- Enter your Stripe API keys in the corresponding fields, and configure the other settings such as title, payment action, and order status.
- Save the configuration and test the Stripe payment method by placing a test order.

To create a custom payment method using Stripe payment, you can follow these steps:

- Create a new module in your Magento 2 store. You can use the module creator tool or create the module manually.
- Define the new payment method in the module's configuration file. You can define the payment method's title, code, and other settings.
- Create a new payment model for the custom payment method. The payment model should extend the Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod class and implement the necessary methods such as authorize(), capture(), and refund().
- In the payment model, use the Stripe API to handle the payment transactions. You can use the official Stripe PHP library or any other third-party library to integrate with the Stripe API.
- Once the payment model is ready, configure the custom payment method in the Magento 2 store by going to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods and selecting the new payment method.
- Test the custom payment method by placing a test order and making a payment using Stripe payment.